# Scala save future value to variable

Tags: scala, codeigniter

my function to insert person:

```
def InsertPerson = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
val b = request.body.validate[Person]
b.fold(
  //errorForm => Future.successful(Ok(views.html.index(errorForm, Seq.empty[User]))),
  errors => {
    BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))
  },
  person => {
    val f = ApplTagService.insertPerson(person)
      f.map(res => "User successfully added").recover {
        case ex: Error => ex.getMessage
      }
      f onFailure {
        case t => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
    }

    Ok(Json.obj("status" -> f.toString() ))

  })}
```

I send Json from CI to scala for insert person, then I want to give an alert if that insert is success or not, I need to save `ex.getMessage` or `t.getMessage` on a variable and send it to CI

what I get now on `f.toString()` in CI is `scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@793e6657`

How can I show `ex.getMessage` or `t.getMessage` in CI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json)` instead of `Action(BodyParsers.parse.json)` when you want to return a `Future[Result]` instead of a `Result`

In this case your match will look like this

```
b.fold(
  errors => Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))),
  person => {
    val f = ApplTagService.insertPerson(person)
    val fMessage = f.map(res => "User successfully added").recover {
      case ex: Error => ex.getMessage
    }
    f onFailure {
      case t => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
    }

    fMessage.map(message => Ok(Json.obj("status" -> message )))
})
```